# Opening IPhone app when reaches a particular location?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, location, cllocationmanager

Is there any way to open an iphone app without user interaction , like reminder setting etc

I want to open my iphone app when the user reaches a particular lat and long, if it is possible please give me an idea
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You'll turn on location services and request location updates while in the background.

[Location Services](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/CoreLocation/CoreLocation.html)

But you will not be able to launch the app. You will be able to post a notification.

[Notifications Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is only one way: 
The significant location service from Apple Location Api.

This will really open your app, even when it is terminated.
(Drawback: not accurate, up to 1000m because based on cell tower / wifi))

The other solution: Your app runs in background, consumes GPS positions regulary:
+/- : acurate up to some meters, needs more batterfy, app can be terminated by user